# Encuentra el número con la secuencia más larga en el arreglo en C#

Tags: c#

Me piden escribir un programa que imprima el numero que tiene mas ocurrencias seguidas en un  arreglo y también imprimir la cantidad de veces que aparece en la secuencia, es decir, debe imprimir algo de este estilo:

- La secuencia más larga: 3
- El número con la secuencia más larga: 8

Hasta el momento solo tengo la repetición de cada uno, la verdad no he podido avanzar más:

```
int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8 };
Array.Sort(myArray);
int cont = 0;
int aux = myArray[0];
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
   if (aux == myArray[i])
   {
       cont++;
   }else
   {
       Console.Write(cont + ",");
       cont=1;
       aux=myArray[i];
   }
}
Console.Write(cont );
```

Agradezco su pronta colaboración.

Comment: Hola Bryan, podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles, y marcar como aceptada la q mas te haya ayudado, y si lo deseas emitir tu voto tambien, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Con linq puedes hacerlo de manera muy sencilla:

```
int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8 };
```

Utilizando la expresion group by agrupamos el array en listados con el mismo valor,despues ordenamos estos listados por numero de elementos, de esta manera obtendremos el grupo con mayor longitud:

```
var GreaterGroup = myArray.GroupBy(v => v).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count()).First();
```

Ahora tomamos el primer numero de este grupo:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Greater group value: {GreaterGroup.First()}");
```

Contamos la longitud del grupo:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Longest group: {GreaterGroup.Count()}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **Linq**:

```
var elemento = (from a in myArray
                group a by a into grupo
                select new 
                {
                   Numero = grupo.Key,
                   Repeticiones = grupo.Count()
                }
               ).OrderByDescending(x => x.Repeticiones).
                 FirstOrDefault()
```

Hasta aquí se hace una agrupación donde se va a seleccionar la cantidad de veces que sale determinado número en el arreglo, devolviéndose una **lista de objetos anónimos**, donde cada **objeto anónimo** tendrá dos propiedades de tipo **int** (**propiedad Numero** y **propiedad Repeticiones**) ordenándose descendentemente por su **propiedad Repeticiones** y seleccionando solo el primer elemento de la lista, es decir se ordena por el número que más veces se repite.

Hasta aquí todo muy bien, pero que sucede si existen varios números con la misma cantidad de repeticiones, por ejemplo el **número 8** aparece **3** veces y el **número 1** aparece también **3** veces. Para solucionar esto debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var listaNumeros = (from a in myArray
                    group a by a into grupo
                    select new 
                    {
                       Numero = grupo.Key,
                       Repeticiones = grupo.Count()
                    }
                   ).Where(x => x.Repeticiones == elemento.Repeticiones)
```

Se hace otra consulta **Linq** muy parecida a la anterior, pero esta vez se seleccionarán todos los números que tienen la misma cantidad de repeticiones.

Posteriormente mediante un **ciclo foreach** se imprimirían los números que más repeticiones tienen:

```
foreach (var l in listaNumeros)
{
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Número: {0}; Repeticiones: {1} ", l.Numero, l.Repeticiones));
}
```

Para poder usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

**Nota:** Esto puede optimizarse mucho más, e incluso quizá todo pudiera solucionarse con una sola consulta **Linq**.